# How do I fix my command prompt now being able to run and command prompt applications?

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

I cannot open any command prompt applications inside of my command prompt (Windows 10). These include things like SFC or DISM. I cant run pip or anything like that. Why is it broken and how do I fix it?

Whenever I try to run a command prompt application it says "Command application" not recongnized or external command

I tried restarting my pc and fixing system files. Neither worked.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What does "I can't run" mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: I will like to see the error message you're receiving if any so we can assist you

Comment: Whenever I try and run the command it says "command application" not recognized or external command.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.